# Syntax error for elif statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a begginer and I am trying to recreate the modern periodic table in Python. For some reason, it shows a syntax error for my elif statement which seems to be perfectly fine to me. I use VS Code as my primary editor, so I copy pasted the code to sublime text and even it shows the same issue. Can anyone identify the isuue and help me fix the issue. I've attached the code below and the error it shows.

```
ERROR:-
'elif e=='Li' or e=='lithium':
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'Thanks in advance.
```

CODE:-

```
elif e=='Li' or e=='lithium':
    from mendeleev import Li
    print('Name: ', Li.name)
    print('Symbol: ', Li.symbol)
    print('Atomic Number: ',Li.atomic_number)
    print('Group:', Li.group)
    print('Period: ', Li.period)
    print('Block: ', Li.block)
    print('Valence Electrons :', Li.nvalence())
    print('Atomic Mass: ', Li.atomic_weight)
    print('Electronic Configuration: ', Li.ec.conf)
    print('E.C in shells:', Li.ec.electrons_per_shell()
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please copy-paste the full and complete error output *as text* into the question. And add a comment in the code on the line where you get the error. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: send the whole code; in the code you provided there are no errors.

Comment: You cannot have a `elif` without an `if`.

Comment: You didnt close your print statement on the previous line, its missing a `)` at the end

Comment: And almost always when you get such errors in Python code, try counting brackets and parentheses, and make sure all are matching.

Comment: The error shows a `'` before the `elif`. If this accurately represents your code, you need to remove the `'`.

Comment: Side comment/suggestion: I suggest you learn about dictionaries. If you store the element data in a dictionary, you can look it up directly without a long `if...elif...else` chain.

Comment: In addition to what @Code-Apprentice said you might also want to look at a function to print the output so you dont write all the print statements again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your snapshot it seems you missed a `)` every time for your last print statement. look the line above every `elif`. you can see it :

```
print('E.C in shells:', Li.ec.electrons_per_shell()   <---- here!
```

just add a parenthesis.

Comment: if you find this answer useful please accept it as the answer  :)

Comment: Thanks it worked. It was a careless error on my side

Comment: @PraninEdward And this is the kind of thing that is difficult to see when you've been staring at the same code for a long time. It helps to have another set of eyes.